# Count Duplicated Services in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL View with records of people that get some kinds of food. It looks like this:

```
**Person|Quantity|Service|

Person1|1|Type1A|20150101

Person2|1|Type1A|20150101

Person1|1|Type1B|20150101

Person1|1|Type1C|20150101

Person2|1|Type1C|20150101

Person2|1|Type2A|20150101
.....
```

I need to filter the records that meet certain criteria like this:

*All the Personas that has more than (2 of the Type1 Services or more than 3 of Type2 Services) in the same day.

I was trying with something like this:

```
SELECT *,
 Count(CASE WHEN SERVICE= 'Type1A' OR SERVICE='Type1B' then 1 else null end) as Type1
FROM TABLE
```

But clearly it is not working..

Comment: Try using a SUM instead of a COUNT, and counting 1 vs 0 instead of 1 vs NULL.   And by the way, you need to use GROUP BY Person, and you can't include * in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
person from
(

    Select
    person,
    count (case when service like'Type1%' then 1 else null end) as Type1,
    count (case when service like 'Type2%' then 1 else null end) as Type2
    from
    <your table>
    group by person
    ) t 
    where 
    (type1 > 2 or type2 > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can do this:

```
SELECT person
FROM (
    SELECT person
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN service LIKE 'Type1%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS Type1
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN service LIKE 'Type2%'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS Type2
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY person
    ) t
WHERE (
        type1 > 2
        OR type2 > 3
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation in `having` clause:

```
select Person from Persons
group by Person
having sum(case when Servise like 'Type1%' then 1 else 0 end) > 2 or
       sum(case when Servise like 'Type2%' then 1 else 0 end) > 3
```